# Delphi 7 e Openssl

Tags: delphi, openssl

Possuo um servidor `Ubuntu` na web e tenho total controle do mesmo, é um `VPS`, tenho um `restful` feito em `django` que consigo ler tranquilamente no `Delphi7` com o superobjects.

A minha preocupação é que essa comunicação é texto, portanto qualquer sniffer pode capturar os dados traferados e interpretá-los facilmente, eu estudei o básico do `SSL/TLS` e como ele funciona, consigo configurar um `OPENSSL` no servidor, a minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho diversos clients em Delphi rodando, terei que baixar a chave privada e o configurar em cada máquina para conseguir conectar de formar segura?

Sei que usando `openssl` com gmail e hotmail não se precisa baixar nada no cliente, ele já autentica transparentemente passando apenas o login e a senha.

Consigo algo semelhante fazendo https usando o `Delphi7` com indy por exemplo, o que quero evitar é instalar certificados, isso vai  dar muito trabalho.